# Friendlyarm deleted notofocation-daemon service

Tags: services, d-bus, notifications

I did some tests with my device with FriendlyArm and broke some important things.
I can't login into the system.
`/var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log` contains a lot of  `(nm-applet:987): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:29:15.144: ((libnm-core/nm-setting-connection.c:220)): assertion '<dropped>' failed` strings which [can be because of errors with notification-daemon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473364/nm-applet-does-not-respond-to-clicks-on-the-tray-icon-unless-started-with-sudo)
and this one:
`(nm-applet:987): nm-applet-WARNING **: 12:29:22.518: Failed to show notification: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files`
which proves my guess.
`ls /usr/share/dbus-1/services/ | grep -i noti` gives me nothing.
I tried to do:
`sudo apt install libnotify-cil-dev` it doesn't work
Wrote

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
```

to `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service` (notify-daemon package is installed and I checked that binary is available with this path) and this gave me new error:
`(nm-applet:994): nm-applet-WARNING **: 13:30:32.786: Failed to show notification: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications exited with status 1`

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a notifier depending on the setup of your system, e.g. `dunst` or `mako-notifier`.